# Sending out bulk HTML formatted emails with one time login links

Tags: wysiwyg, theming, emails, users

I'm making a new webshop for a client, and the idea is, once it goes online to send existing users an email saying:

'hey, we have a new site, and while we're at it, check out these new offers we have'

However, I wouldn't want it to be only plain text, as thats not very efficient in luring customers and the email has to contain a one-time login link, cause I wasn't able to get the passwords from the old D6 website due to changes in the encryption algorithm. Currently, I'm using the one-time login module, which does the job, but doesn't let me to HTML format the mail template.

My question is:
Is there a solution readily available for this, i.e. to embed wysiwyg editor to the mail template (under admin/config/people/accounts), or can someone suggest another module, that can both handle one time login links and supports HTML mails? Or maybe a solution outside drupal, that somehow integrates with it, and is possibly free of charge?

https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail - or may this module be eligible for the task? And if yes, can someone give me some hints on how to get it working the way I need to?

Thanks in advance!
Huba

Comment: HTMLmail + mailsystem + theme your email.

Comment: thx! will give it a try!